# Mac OS X locate command returning nothing

Tags: macos, locate

I don't get an error about the db not existing or being populated. I get nothing. I know for a fact that the things I'm searching for exist on my box. I even tried `locate bin` or `locate Users`. I get nothing!

I tried updating the db: `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`, but still nothing.

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` says that it's already loaded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It says it's already loaded :(

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for some things is `mdfind` (`mdfind` and related utilities are the command line interface to Spotlight). But it only finds things that Spotlight itself would return.

But keeping the focus on `locate`, check to make sure that `/var/db/locate.database` is actually populated. Or to start from scratch disable locate via `launchctl`, run `locate.updatedb` as root then reload locate via `launchctl`. This should leave you with a working database.

Answer (score 0):

2011 comments under [Automatically update locate db on-demand - Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111007011922833) recall that Apple ceased use of the database by default. From [`updatedb.sh` in open source for Mac OS X 10.5.8](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-118/locate/locate/updatedb.sh.auto.html):

> WARNING
>
> Executing updatedb as root.  This WILL reveal all filenames 
>   on your machine to all login users, which is a security risk.

If understand correctly, from more recent answers under [Including Directories in Locate on Mac OS X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177172/13260) (2015-01-03):

- if the user chooses to override Apple's default and populate the database, then the result will properly exclude most of what's in the user's home directory.